# Doing POST from devtool not working anymore

Tags: php, google-chrome-extension, http-post

I'm building a chrome devtools extension. I was doing a POST to one of my files on the server:

```
$.post( "http://example.com/post.php",
{ name: q1, name2: q2 },
```

In my post.php I clearly specified access for all:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

But now when I run my extension it doesn't work and I get the following error in console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/post.php. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://mpggm***************fbkjf' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

The problem is that it worked for months and now all of the sudden it doesn't. I then installed everything from the backup files but the problem remains. What am I missing her?? Did Google change something??

I checked the console > network response (of the extension), this is what I get:

> Request URL:http://*****.com/post.php Request Headers Provisional
>   headers are shown Accept:*/*
>   Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>   Origin:chrome-extension://mp**************fbkjf User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/37.0.2062.103 Safari/537.36
>   X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:5C**************CDCD252

These are the headers which I aspect derived from an online web page (so not the extension):

> Connection:Keep-Alive
>   Content-Length:44
>   Content-Type:text/html
>   Date:Sat, 06 Sep 2014 10:45:14 GMT
>   Keep-Alive:timeout=2, max=100
>   Server:Apache
>   X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.25-1~dotdeb.1

Comment: This can mean only one thing. You _think_ you clearly specified it, but you didn't, or you're accessing the wrong address. Double-check both server-side and the POST request.

Comment: Can you verify from monitoring network requests that you ARE getting the header? Maybe with [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm)

Comment: @Xan I put some additional info in my question about the headers. So `Accept:*/*` nothing wrong there (right..??)

Comment: Those are _request_ headers, you should be looking at the response.

Comment: @Xan I have put(copy/paste) all the headers shown in the console/network (except the form data/not important). So that means there is no response, which makes sense because Im getting blocked in the first place....

Comment: @Xan I have put some more info in the question. I have an online webpage which I use to test the php file on its response. I have looked at the network response from that page, so this is what to aspect when it works in devtool

Comment: It does not show the header...is that what you mean..?

Comment: I just tested it in jsfiddle and Im getting the same blocking message so its the php file after all...which is kinda weird because I did not alter that file. But anyway I have to look for a better way to allow acces. @Xan thanks for your time

Comment: You can allow access by declaring host permissions for your service. Then, cross-site requests will succeed regardless of CORS setup.